# How to change date in datepicker using Appium

Tags: java, android, datepicker, appium

I'm trying to change the date in a datepicker element using appium. I can't use the ***findElement(By.id("id");*** since I'm running in version 4.2.2(API 17) and as far as i know By.id is not supported in this version. Using selendroid i can change the date like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("MONTH")).sendKeys("FEB");
```

In my code in appium I try to access it by the default date. For example im trying to change the month like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Dec")).sendKeys("Jan");
```

It seems that although it finds the name  Dec it can't send the keys Jan.

Here is the error from the Failure Trace:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Any ides on how i can change it and generally if i can use somehow the ***findElement(By.id("id");*** in this API version?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the ***By.name*** i used ***By.className*** in order to change the month the day and the year. Here is my code:

```
List<WebElement> date = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.NumberPicker"));
    date.get(0).sendKeys("Apr");
    date.get(1).sendKeys("17");
    date.get(2).sendKeys("1972");
```

Comment: Note that this is working only on API level 17. Currently I'm trying to find a way to test it for API level 19. The reason why this is different its because the datepicker for newest android versions is different and we have to choose other elements to send the month, day and year

Comment: Did you find how to do it on API levels >= 19 ?